# dplyr::case_when vs if_else for summary column requiring two conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df<-data.frame('id'=c(1:6),
'start_date'=c('Mar-22','Feb-22','Jan-22','Dec-21','Nov-21','Oct-21'),
'Jan-22'= c(NA,NA,1,0,0,1),
'Feb-22'= c(NA,1,1,0,0,1))
```

I would like to figure out if I can nest case_when or if_else functions within the dplyr::mutate function to get a new column. The new column should show if the value of the month column 3 months after start date has a value of 1 or not. I can write a case_when as shown:

```
df2<-df%>%
mutate(3_month_followup=case_when(start_date=='Oct-21'&'Jan-22'==1~'yes))
```

This works fine, but only allows for testing one interval before pasting the answer. is there a way to include all 3 month intervals in this function?

Expected outcome:

```
#id     start_date     Jan-22     Feb-22     3mofollowup
#1      Mar-22         NA         NA         NA
#2      Feb-22         NA         1          NA
#3      Jan-22         1          1          NA 
#4      Dec-21         0          0          NA
#5      Nov-21         0          0          no
#6      Oct-21         1          1          yes
```

Comment: You can have mutliple expressions in `case_when`.   Please show your expected

Comment: I know. I don't know how to nest them so that I have conditionA &conditionB | conditionC & condition D....etc.

Comment: How big is your data? Converting all the follow-up columns to long format would be the "tidy" way to do this.

Comment: Alternatively, I could imagine turning all the 1s in the follow-up columns in to a single `list` column with the dates, and then checking that.

Comment: over 700 id numbers and 14 months of data. I'm not sure I follow how transposing the followup column would help. And you mean like make a column of expected followup and check if true? I feel like I'd still run into the same issue of having different sets of conditions for different rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this took a little doing. I left the helper columns in to illustrate, but you can drop them, of course. (And probably condense some of them, if you'd like.)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

date_cols = names(df)[names(df) %>% endsWith("22")]
df %>% 
  mutate(
    follow_up = pmap(select(., all_of(date_cols)), c),
    follow_up_date = lapply(follow_up, \(x) date_cols[x == 1]),
    start_date_date = as.Date(paste0("01-", start_date), format = "%d-%b-%y"),
    `3modate` = start_date_date + months(3),
    `3mostring` = format(`3modate`, "%b-%y"),
    `3mofollowup` = map2(`3mostring`, follow_up_date, ~ifelse(any(.x == .y), "yes", "no")),
    `3mofollowup` = ifelse(!`3mostring` %in% date_cols, NA, `3mofollowup`)
  )
#   id start_date Jan-22 Feb-22 follow_up follow_up_date start_date_date    3modate 3mostring
# 1  1     Mar-22     NA     NA    NA, NA         NA, NA      2022-03-01 2022-06-01    Jun-22
# 2  2     Feb-22     NA      1     NA, 1     NA, Feb-22      2022-02-01 2022-05-01    May-22
# 3  3     Jan-22      1      1      1, 1 Jan-22, Feb-22      2022-01-01 2022-04-01    Apr-22
# 4  4     Dec-21      0      0      0, 0                     2021-12-01 2022-03-01    Mar-22
# 5  5     Nov-21      0      0      0, 0                     2021-11-01 2022-02-01    Feb-22
# 6  6     Oct-21      1      1      1, 1 Jan-22, Feb-22      2021-10-01 2022-01-01    Jan-22
#   3mofollowup
# 1          NA
# 2          NA
# 3          NA
# 4          NA
# 5          no
# 6         yes
```

Commented version:

```
## identify date columns
date_cols = names(df)[names(df) %>% endsWith("22")]
df %>% 
  mutate(
    ## turn the date columns into a single list column
    follow_up = pmap(select(., all_of(date_cols)), c),
    ## get the col names where the date cols have a 1
    follow_up_date = lapply(follow_up, \(x) date_cols[x == 1]),
    ## make a Date class version of `start_date`
    start_date_date = as.Date(paste0("01-", start_date), format = "%d-%b-%y"),
    ## add 3 months to the start date so we know when to look
    `3modate` = start_date_date + months(3),
    ## convert the 3modate to a string of the same format as the col names
    `3mostring` = format(`3modate`, "%b-%y"),
    ## look for the string
    ## using any() here rather than just `%in%` to keep the NAs in the result
    `3mofollowup` = map2(`3mostring`, follow_up_date, ~ifelse(any(.x == .y), "yes", "no")),
    ## check that the 3 month followup was possible
    `3mofollowup` = ifelse(!`3mostring` %in% date_cols, NA, `3mofollowup`)
  )
```